# python, нужно подставлять все слова из файла в ссылку по одному, и в другой файл записывать куда эта ссылка перенаправила

Tags: python, html, парсер, requests, site

Например:
Файл1:

Test

Example

Proverka

Код переходит по ссылке example.com/[word]/start, подставляя вместо [word] слова из файла 1.
Каждая из получившихся ссылок редиректит на другой сайт, нужно записать все ссылки после редиректа в файл 2.
Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Читаете файл, делаете запрос, записываете ссылки. Или надо за вас написать?

Comment: Не совсем понятно как понять куда перенаправила ссылка(

Comment: Попробуйте сделать запрос на нужную вам страницу и посмотрите что он вам отправит

Comment: (спойлер: HTML страницу с ссылкой)

Comment: Этот код - import requests
agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get("url", headers = agent)
print(r) даёт Response: 403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, я могу посоветовать  использовать модуль `requests` для выполнения запросов и модуль `re` для поиска и извлечения URL-адресов после редиректа. Вот пример кода:

```py
import requests
import re

# Открывает файл для чтения и считывает слова
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file:
    words = file.read().splitlines()

# Открывает файл для записи
with open('file2.txt', 'w') as file:
    # Перебирает слова
    for word in words:
        # Формирует ссылку
        url = f'http://example.com/{word}/start'
        try:
            # Выполняет GET-запрос
            response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
            # Проверяет статус код ответа
            if 300 <= response.status_code < 400:
                # Извлекает URL-адрес после редиректа
                redirected_url = response.headers['Location']
                # Записывает URL-адрес в файл
                file.write(redirected_url + '\n')
            else:
                # Если ответ не является редиректом
                file.write('No redirect\n')
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
            # Обрабатывает ошибки запроса
            file.write('Error\n')
```

> Ты только должен поменять 'file1.txt' на имя своего файла, содержащего слова, и 'file2.txt' на имя файла, в который ты хочешь сохранить URL-адреса после редиректа.

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ, но на сайте стоит cloudflare который обойти у меня не получилось:( Достиг результата другим путем. А так ваш ответ может помочь другим:)